# Xdebug configuration with Vim

Tags: php, vim, xdebug

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 using php 7.4.18 and apache and has its document root at `/var/www/html` . This is my php --version

```
PHP 7.4.18 (cli) (built: May  3 2021 11:27:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.18, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

my xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

My .vimrc

```
let g:vdebug_options = {"port": 9000, "break-on-open": 0, }
```

I have a wordpress installation in `/var/www/html/wordress`  and when i try to debug in vim it is showing "Vdebug will wait for a connection" even if i access "localhost/wordpress"  with `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1` ( I tried installing Xdebug Helper for chrome ) it is not connecting .

What other things i have tried

1. I added the xdebug.ini code to php.ini but couldn't get it connected .
2. Added `"path_maps": {'/':'/var/www/html'}` to vdebut_option in vimrc.

Please help and let me know what am i doing wrong ?

This is my xdebug_info() screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting Xdebug 2 settings, but running Xdebug 3:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

You need to convert these to Xdebug 3 settings, as per the [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide).
The `xdebug_info()` output that you shared has links to the "Docs" (most right column) too, and it shows that "Step Debugger" is not enabled.

Comment: changed the settings to `xdebug.mode=debug xdebug.start_with_request=yes`  as Derick said if somebody else is having the problem please go through the upgrade guide .